# Flick WordCount example failing with java.lang.NoSuchMethodError Exception

Tags: apache-flink

I am trying to execute the basic WordCount example in Flink which is present in the below link -
[Link](https://github.com/apache/flink/blob/master/flink-examples/flink-examples-batch/src/main/java/org/apache/flink/examples/java/wordcount/WordCount.java)

When I run it from eclipse, its failing with the below exception -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.flink.core.memory.MemorySegmentFactory.initializeFactory(Lorg/apache/flink/core/memory/MemorySegmentFactory$Factory;)V
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$.parseTaskManagerConfiguration(TaskManager.scala:1936)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.taskmanager.TaskManager$.startTaskManagerComponentsAndActor(TaskManager.scala:1684)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.LocalFlinkMiniCluster.startTaskManager(LocalFlinkMiniCluster.scala:118)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:270)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster$$anonfun$2.apply(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:263)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.immutable.Range.foreach(Range.scala:141)
at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
at scala.collection.AbstractTraversable.map(Traversable.scala:105)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.start(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:263)
at org.apache.flink.runtime.minicluster.FlinkMiniCluster.start(FlinkMiniCluster.scala:236)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.start(LocalExecutor.java:115)
at org.apache.flink.client.LocalExecutor.executePlan(LocalExecutor.java:173)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.LocalEnvironment.execute(LocalEnvironment.java:91)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.ExecutionEnvironment.execute(ExecutionEnvironment.java:926)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.collect(DataSet.java:410)
at org.apache.flink.api.java.DataSet.print(DataSet.java:1605)
at org.hemant.notifier.stream.WordCount.main(WordCount.java:74)
```

Any idea how to address this?

Thanks

Comment: what dependencies do you have in your pom.xml ?

Comment: @Derlin You are right. Had issues with pom.xml. this is the updated one -

Answer (score 1):

The `MemorySegmentFactory` class is part of `flink-core`. Your problem might be that you forgot some flink dependencies.

**maven/java**

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-java</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.flink</groupId>
    <artifactId>flink-clients_2.11</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.4</version>
</dependency>
```

(set the versions to your version of flink and change `_2.11` to `_2.10` if you use scala 2.10)

**sbt/scala**

```
version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.11.8"

libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
   "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-scala" % "1.2.0",
   "org.apache.flink" %% "flink-clients" % "1.2.0"
 )
```

(again, update the versions to match yours)

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me was the dependency order.

`flink-java` should be placed **after** either `flink-clients` or `flink-test-utils` in the list of dependencies.